# Kentico Address Name automatically updated

Tags: kentico

The Kentico database contains a field COM_Address.AddressName that is overwritten anytime I attempt to update it.

There is some process that replaces the contents of the AddressName column with some type of pre-determined address label, that's something along the lines of

```
"Address 1 + "," + City + "," + State", ....
```

I've been unable to determine what process is updating this field, or how to control it.

I'd like to use this column to store an address name, like "John Smith".

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In version 7 there is a method `AddressInfoProvider.GetAddressName(AddressInfo addressObj)` which is being called on multiple places from UI (controls and pages) and which constructs the address as you describe. If you want to change its behavior I recommend to write a [custom provider](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/custom_providers_writing.htm).